# How many languages write their novels in the past tense?

Tags: narrator, chinese-language

I've noticed that it's a norm to write stories in the past tense in most of European literary traditions. But how frequenly does it appear outside Europe?  In Classical Chinese, they always wrote history in the psedo-present tense, and the pluperfect was often used to clear the sequence, which is very unusual in Modern Chinese. It lacks many aspects which exist in Modern Chinese since many of the texts read like English to me, but it never marked the past tense.
I can't talk of Indian or Persian literary traditions; how do they differ from European traditions in terms of the narrative tense?

Comment: I wonder if you're comparing apples and oranges. In all European languages, most of the time, you cannot speak without choosing past or non-past forms of verbs (of course there may be further options). But if the language doesn't have grammaticalized ways of conveying tense, then unmarked verbals are not "present" but "untensed".

Comment: What is the pluperfect in Classical Chinese?

Answer (score -1):

I think that is just each writer's personal choice. I am fluent in 3 languages and in all of them, literature can be in any tense. As has been commented above, the choice made by the writer can be less noticeable in languages that don't have to explicitly state a tense. An example I can think of is Swahili, where, depending on the style of writing (e.g poetic), tense may be fluid and up to interpretation.